# How to represent an iterable attribute using graphml format

Tags: graph, graphml

I have an example of a graph with a graph property named `random` that has a value of `23`. Is there a way to represent say a list of values as a graph attribute in this format without violating the core format?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
    http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">

  <key id="g_random" for="graph" attr.name="random" attr.type="double"/>
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
    <data key="g_random">23</data> 
    <node id="n0">
    </node>
    <node id="n1">
    </node>
    <edge source="n0" target="n1">
    </edge>
 </graph>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a `string` data type to encode the data within the array. **There is no native way** to represent iterable data types with this format at the time of this posting. Here is an example of a `node` attribute with an array of values associated with it, in graphml format:

```
<graphml 
<!-- Boilerplate graphml -->

<key id="v_arr" for="node" attr.name="arr" attr.type="string"/>
<graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
:
:

<node id="n0">
  <data key="v_arr">23 4 5</data>
</node>
<node id="n1">
  <data key="v_arr">34.3 53.34</data>
</node>
<node id="n2">
  <data key="v_arr">45.4 23E-23</data>
</node>
<edge source="n0" target="n2">
</edge>
```